# Using postgres triggers to update tag counts efficiently

Tags: sql, postgresql, triggers, tagging

I have a schema where users have tags associated with them:

```
user_id: int4    tags: text[]
-------------    ------------
1                [ 'apple', 'carrot', 'jelly' ]
2                [ 'jelly', 'zebra' ]
```

I am looking to create query that returns the list of all tags along with their associated counts. Example:

```
tag: text      count: int4
---------      -----------
'apple'        1
'carrot'       1
'jelly'        2
'zebra'        1
```

Triggers seem to be the ideal way to do this, since the application is read-heavy and write-light.

However, I am having difficulty implementing this. The trigger itself seems simple enough I think:

```
CREATE TRIGGER tags_count_update
AFTER UPDATE OF tags ON person
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE trigger_update_tags_count();
```

The `trigger_update_tags_count` is the part I'm having trouble with, because it seems to be a highly complex operation. For example, if  the tag doesn't already exist in the `tags` table then it should be inserted with a count of 1.

Also, I believe you need to do some sort of diff operation, because if someone's tags are updated from `[ 'apple', 'carrot', 'jelly' ]` to `[ 'apple', 'dogs' ]` then `apple`'s count doesn't change, `carrot` and `jelly` is decremented by 1, and `dogs` is created with its count set to 1. This is compounded with the fact that tags are arrays. I currently have something like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.trigger_update_tags_count()
  RETURNS trigger
  LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$
BEGIN
   INSERT INTO tags (tag, count) VALUES (new.tag, 1)
   ON CONFLICT (tag) DO UPDATE
   SET count = CASE WHEN (tag.new AND NOT tag.old) THEN count + 1 
                    WHEN (tag.old AND NOT tag.new) THEN count - 1
                    ELSE count
               END
   RETURN NEW;
END;
$function$;
```

Which is slightly pseudocode because I'm not sure how to integrate the fact that I'm dealing with text arrays, nor how to handle the diffing case.

Answer (score 2):

You have nothing called `tag` in the data; it is `tags`.  So you need to `UNNEST()` and to handle both old and new tags.  I'm thinking something like:

```
INSERT INTO tags (tag, count) 
   SELECT COALESCE(ntag, otag),
          (ntag IS NOT NULL)::int - (otag IS NOT NULL)::int
   FROM UNNEST(new.tags) ntag FULL JOIN
        UNNEST(old.tags) otag
        ON ntag = otag
ON CONFLICT (tag) DO UPDATE
   SET count = count + (excluded.ntag IS NOT NULL)::int - (excluded.otag IS NOT NULL)::int
```

Comment: Thanks for looking into this! Hmm, I'm currently getting `db error: ERROR: column excluded.ntag does not exist`. Not sure if I'm doing something wrong though.

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure if this answer is correct. Wouldn't count only ever be `-1, 0, or 1` with this? And the target table I'm inserting into only has a `tag` column and a `count` column, so `excluded.ntag` doesn't exist. Well, in any case I'll keep poking at it and hopefully I can make it work.

Comment: I think this might be it? https://pastebin.com/MyrCKbmq Seems to be working okay so far I think..

Comment: @RyanPeschel . . . The `set` clause was missing the all important `count +`.

Answer (score 0):

I am unsure that you do need a trigger a complex logic for that. You can get the output that you want with a simple query that leverages [Postgres' array function `unnest()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-array.html):

```
select x.tag, count(*)
from mytable t
cross join lateral unnest(t.tags) x(tag)
group by x.tag
```

Note that if you find yourself repeatedly running such query, it is an indication that your design does not really fit your use case; you might be better off storing each `user_id/tag` tuple in a separate table row, separated from the tables where users are stored.

Comment: My `tags` table is not automatically updated. That is what I'm trying to figure out how to do with this question. Updating a user's tags simply updates that column in the person table. This trigger ideally would allow the `tags` table to be in sync with all of the tags that exist and their respective counts.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing a similar problem so tried it by creating some dummy tables code as follows

```
CREATE TABLE public.test_tags(
tags_names text[],
id integer)


CREATE TABLE public.tag_counter(
tag_name text,
tag_count integer,
CONSTRAINT tag_counter_tag_name_key UNIQUE (tag_name))



create or replace function test_count() returns trigger as $func$ 

begin
INSERT INTO tag_counter(tag_name) 
   SELECT UNNEST(new.tags_names) ntag
   except 
   select UNNEST(old.tags_names)
        ON CONFLICT (tag_name)  DO UPDATE
   SET tag_count = tag_counter.tag_count + 1;
INSERT INTO tag_counter(tag_name) 
      SELECT UNNEST(old.tags_names) otag
   except 
   select UNNEST(new.tags_names)
        ON CONFLICT (tag_name)  DO UPDATE
   SET tag_count = tag_counter.tag_count - 1;
   return new;     
END; 
$func$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;

create trigger test_update after update on test_tags for each row execute procedure test_count()
```

It's working fine but doesn't think its production-ready if possible can you share your code